# Опция uwsgi_cache_background_update в nginx

Tags: nginx, кэширование

Настроил кэширование в nginx. Конфигурация примерно следующая:

```py
uwsgi_cache            tcache;
uwsgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 10s;
uwsgi_ignore_headers Vary Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
uwsgi_cache_key        "$scheme://$host$uri$is_args$args$vary";
uwsgi_cache_background_update on;
uwsgi_cache_lock on;
uwsgi_cache_use_stale updating;
```

Собственно дальше начинаю тестировать и смотреть, что лежит в 
$upstream_cache_status. В целом все прекрасно, каждые 10 секунд попадает STALE.
А вопрос в том, почему у меня, в случае попадания в STALE, starttransfer_time сильно отличается от total_time?

Статистика запросов примерно следующая. 
Попадание в HIT:

```
{"total_time": 0.044069, "starttransfer_time": 0.022323} 
{"total_time": 0.035173, "starttransfer_time": 0.012174} 
{"total_time": 0.059439, "starttransfer_time": 0.016957}
```

Попадание в STALE:

```
{"total_time": 0.333502, "starttransfer_time": 0.026432}
{"total_time": 0.235473, "starttransfer_time": 0.01763}
{"total_time": 0.22749, "starttransfer_time": 0.018052}
```

Comment: запрос на бекенд уходит

Comment: Нет, добавил time.sleep(5) на ответ бэка. total_time стал почти равен starttransfer_time.